# Login session destroy after page reload/refresh

Tags: php, session

I've problem to understand how different browsers handle my script differently. First please take a look at this simple code that I use for validating users.

```
<?php
session_start ();
if (!isset($_SESSION["login"] , $_SESSION['email'])) 
{
header("location: index.php");
};
include ("DBconn.php");
?>
```

After session successfully created and I enter the page, what happen is when I reload the page the login session that has been created before somehow destroy/missing and I redirect to login page. I try to check the session ID and it did not change. This issue happens in FF and Chrome latest version, it not happen in Opera 18 or Chrome older version. Please can someone give some help to solve this issue. Many thanks.

Here is my complete login.php.

```
<?php
session_start ();
include ("DBconn.php");


$email = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST['email']); 
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST['pass']); 
$passi_db = md5 ($_REQUEST['pass']); 


$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
$mail = mysql_query ($query);




if (mysql_num_rows ($mail) == 1)
{

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email' AND pass_db = '$pass_db' AND active = 1";
$password = mysql_query ($query);


if (mysql_num_rows ($password ) == 1)
{


    $d = mysql_fetch_array($password );
    $operator = $d['operator_1'];

    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    $data["status"] = "yes";
    $data["operator"] = $operator;
    echo json_encode($data);    



    }
else 
{

    $data["status"] = "NOTmatch";
    echo json_encode($data);    
    }
}
 else 
{


$data["status"] = "emailNOTexist";
echo json_encode($data);    

}


mysql_close ();

?>
```

Comment: Does `index.php` invoke `session_start()`?

Comment: you need to add session_start (); to all your pages on top.

Comment: No it doesn't. Should I?

Comment: I've try put it but still got same result.

Comment: What is pretty sure, is that it's not a browser issue

Comment: Can you echo $_SESSION['login'] and $_SESSION['email']?

Comment: @FabienWarniez yes of course the problem is both were destroy after I reload the page.

Comment: Can you tell us what "echo" prints? Does it print NULL? Does it generate an undefined notice?

Comment: Do you manipulate the $_SESSION variables anywhere else?

Comment: the login shows "1" and the email shows user email.

Comment: Yes to put order request. $_SESSION['order'], $_SESSION['TransactionNumber']

Comment: seeing your login.php, it's seems that your login is made via an AJAX call, is that right ?

Comment: @CtrlX that's right. I called it from the front page. The problem seems that certain browser doesn't remember my logged in that I've stored in $_SESSION[]. The browsers have no problem remembering the session_id(). Any suggestion?

Comment: Did I properly store my logged in session in $_SESSION[]?

Comment: I try to use var_dump($_SESSION); to display all sessions keys and the out put is like this: array(2) { ["login"]=> int(1) ["email"]=> string(17) "animous@yahoo.com" }. Does it means all the sessions are properly stored? I'm confussed..

Comment: Yes, it mean that your session is fine, so the prbolem is maybe in your javascript or ajax

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `session_start()` on all your pages.

Comment: I've already put it in my index.php but still got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

isset will check existence of both parametre and return true only if both are set.

'login' or 'email' seems more a ' login OR email condition', so you may try :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["login"]) && !isset($_SESSION['email'])) 
{
   header("location: index.php");
   exit(); // just in case, you can already exit the execution
};
```

Hope this will help

Comment: can you edit your question by adding the part of your login code that save $_SESSION['login'] and $_SESSION['email'] ?

Comment: Ok @Ctrlx please see my login.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove Space between session_start and "()".
So replace session_start (); with session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Create a header.php file and add `session_start()` to it and include header.php to all your pages on top.

Yes you need to add  on top of your all pages, like on login.php, home.php etc, it will check and continue with your existing/new session values

Answer (score 0):

Im so glad I finally found what's wrong. I have this code in my JS script:

```
    $(window).on ('unload', function(){

    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:'logout.php'

        });

    });
```

What this code do basically logging out every time the page unload. This is my mistake. After I delete it The page works fine. Thank you very much everyone for the suggestion. I learn more from my mistake.

Comment: Yep, for this one we couldn't have helped you ;)